# OpenGraph - choose where og:url points / redirect user and keep tags working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am trying to implement OpenGraph actions and object. It works fine, I am able to create objects and actions in the ticker/Timelime.

My only concern is when you display the object, its title is a link.
But it links to the page I use to generate the object, so there is nothing to display :

object.html.erb

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# name_space: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/name_space#">
<meta property="fb:app_id"        content="APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type"          content="name_space:object" /> 
<meta property="og:url"          content="PATH_TO_METHOD_TO_CREATE_OBJECT?img_link=<%= CGI.escape(@img_link)%>&points=<%=@points%>&description=<%= @description%>" /> 
<meta property="og:title"         content="<%= params[:units_offered] %> Points" /> 
<meta property="og:description"   content="<%= params[:description] %>" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="<%= params[:img_link] %>">
```

if I change the og:url meta tag to the url of my FB page then the object picks my FB page value..

in a perfect I wanted to link to nothing or my FB page.

Any clue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the linter doesn't run javascript, you can do a javascript redirection for the user to go to the place you want.

`<script> location.href = 'http://example.com/the_real_page.php'; </script>`

This way the linter can still see the correct og meta tags, and the user who clicks the link gets redirected to the correct location.

Comment: are you making this dynamic also? constructing the url from the passed in parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location = 'YOUR_HOME_PAGE';
</script>
```